# Online user counting (discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

In the serverinfo command, as for me, how many users are online and offline is the most important, and not only, there are many important things, everything for better design and better recognition of information.
The topic now is precisely counting. I know how to do it. But I have a problem that appeared after updating to discord.js v13 and still has not disappeared. I have been updated to the new version for quite some time.
The bot stopped counting offline users. Sometimes it happens that the bot has to be turned off. After turning it on, I noticed that the offline users equals 0, although on the server on which I check the command of people offline, more than half of the server. The number changes if some user appears online first.
Not everything went smoothly with the rest of the statuses either: online, idle, dnd.
My bot now has the status idle, so it turns out that users with statuses are idle not 6, but 5. With other statuses, on the contrary, let's say there are 6 online users, but the bot messages that there are 7 of them.

```
const lang = require('../bot/languageSelector');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    name: 'serverinfo',
    description: 'Shows information of this Discord server',
    run: async (bot, interaction, colorMe) => {
        let embed = new MessageEmbed();
        let members = interaction.guild.members.cache;
        embed.setColor(colorMe);
        embed.setTitle(`${lang(interaction.user.id, "about")} ${interaction.guild.name}`);
        embed.setFields({
            name: `${lang(interaction.user.id, "byStatuses")}`,
            value: `
                ${lang(interaction.user.id, "online")}: ${members.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "online").size}
                ${lang(interaction.user.id, "idle")}: ${members.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "idle").size}
                ${lang(interaction.user.id, "dnd")}: ${members.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "dnd").size}
                ${lang(interaction.user.id, "offline")}: ${members.filter(member => member.presence?.status == "offline").size}
            `,
            inline: true
        });
        interaction.followUp({embeds: [embed]});
    }
}
```

Comment: What intents does your client have? Does it have presence intent?

Comment: @MrMythical I have all intents included: `const allIntents = new Intents(32767)`, `const bot = new Client({intents: [allIntents]})`.

Comment: Did you also enable them in discord developer portal?

Comment: @MrMythical Yes, I did, I can even show a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I'm not too sure about online, dnd and idle, but I know for the offline ones

You see, if a member is offline, they have no presence. This goes for members who are invisible as well. So `members.filter(mem => mem.presence?.status === "offline")` will ALWAYS return an empty collection.

Since they don't have presence, `mem.presence` will be null. You are also using optional chaining, so it will stop right there. So what your code is basically doing is `members.filter(mem => null === "offline")` which we know will return an empty collection.

However, to bypass this, you can use `members.filter(mem => !mem.presence)` which means that filter members who DON'T have any presences, in other words, filter members that are offline.

For other statuses, it could be because you are using `.cache`. Which means that the members / users aren't stored in the cache UNLESS they send a message when the bot is online, or use one of it's command. To bypass this you can do:

```js
// other code...
let members = await interaction.guild.members.fetch()
// other code...
```

This will fetch all members from the server. This also will store the members in cache so you don't have to fetch them every time.